# Split a vector uniformly in R

Tags: r, vector, split

I have a vector of probabilitites in R  :

```
p =c(0.01,0.02,0.2,0.1,0.07,0.15,0.09)
```

and i want to divide it uniformly into 5 categories according to its range:

```
range(p)[1]
range(p)[2]
range(p)[2]/5
```

for example the **1)** category to contain the probabilities from 0 to 0.04,the **2)** category from 0.04 to 0.08
**3)** category from 0.08 to 0.12
**4)** category from 0.12 to 0.16
**5)** category from 0.16 to 0.20

But i want to implement it automatically.How can i do it ?

Comment: You can do `cut(p, 5)`.

Comment: ooooooooooo thank you i didn;t know that.very thankful @27ϕ9